# Hovering mouse cursor over a plot to display a "corresponding" point in another plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, visualization, eventhandler, dynamic

I'm trying to reproduce a variant of [this view](https://www.google.com/finance?chdnp=1&chdd=1&chds=1&chdv=1&chvs=Logarithmic&chdeh=0&chfdeh=0&chdet=1382294776481&chddm=46920&chddi=86400&chls=Ohlc&q=NASDAQ:AAPL&ntsp=1&ei=9yRkUoi4JMOsqgHJAg), where hovering the mouse over a point highlights its "corresponding" point on all plots:

[image: Google Finance page for AAPL, with a volume chart and the "Slow Stochastic Oscillator"]

In my case, the additional complexion is that the x-axes are not the same (*i.e.* they're not all time), though they do all increase monotonically.

I'm in the process of reading, experimenting, and further exploring based on comments on these threads:

- [Display function value on hover?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17545/display-function-value-on-hover)
- [Display position information out of ListPlots inside a Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4707/display-position-information-out-of-listplots-inside-a-manipulate)
- [Extracting the coordinate of a particular point of interest from a ListPlot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16925/extracting-the-coordinate-of-a-particular-point-of-interest-from-a-listplot)
- [Items known by CurrentValue](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/items-known-by-currentvalue)
- [How to manipulate 2D plots?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7142/how-to-manipulate-2d-plots)
- [Dynamically updating interactive objects in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17018/dynamically-updating-interactive-objects-in-mathematica)
- [Adding custom GridLines to the "automatic" ones](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25373/adding-custom-gridlines-to-the-automatic-ones)

However, I've yet to understand (though perhaps the answer may be in one of those threads) how one would affect a plot based on an event triggered on another plot. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. I'll post my solution when I figure it out, though I'm sure it won't be the best one could do, as I'm still new to Mathematica.

---

After @ssch's answer was posted, I realized I left out some critical details/clarifications.

First, I'm working with discreet data, *i.e.* two `ListPlot`s. That doesn't seem to matter, though. @ssch's example worked for me, using `ListPlot`.

Second, and more importantly, the two x-axes are *not* linear images—_i.e._they do *not* increase uniformly. For example:

[image: Non-uniform example]

The above plots graph the same y-axes, but based on different x-axes. (The dotted gray lines correspond, so one can see how certain areas are "stretched" or "compressed" in the second graph.)

Is there a way to get a corresponding cursor in such a case?

Comment: But still n-th point in first plot is referring to the n-th point in the second?

Comment: I found my answer in another thread: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34611/why-is-this-expression-being-held-and-how-can-i-evaluate-it. But I will post back here when I get it working with a hovering cursor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@belisarius answered my question in [another thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34611/why-is-this-expression-being-held-and-how-can-i-evaluate-it/34620#34620). The following is his code with one modification: replacing `MouseDown` with `MouseMoved`.

```
opts = {Axes -> False, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> {300, 200},  AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio};
td1 = Table[{x, 5 Sin[x] + RandomReal[]}, {x, 1, 10, (10 - 1)/500}];
td2 = {Log[#], #2} & @@@ td1;
f = Nearest[td1 -> Automatic];
g = Nearest[td2 -> Automatic];
DynamicModule[{pt1 = {0, 0}, pt2 = {0, 0}, x1 = First@td1, x2 = First@td2},
 Row@{
   Deploy@EventHandler[Dynamic@
     Graphics[{Point@td1 , Red, PointSize[Large], Point[x1]}, opts, GridLines -> {{x1[[1]]}, {}}], 
     "MouseMoved" :> ({x1, x2} = {td1[[#]], td2[[#]]} &@ f[MousePosition["Graphics"], 1])],
   Deploy@EventHandler[Dynamic@
   Graphics[{Point@td2, Green,  PointSize[Large], Point[x2]}, opts ,GridLines -> {{x2[[1]]}, {}}], 
     "MouseMoved" :> ({x1, x2} = {td1[[#]], td2[[#]]} &@ g[MousePosition["Graphics"], 1])]
}]
```

I'm only copying the answer here for posterity, as a comment may be overlooked (especially as I plan to accept @Kuba's answer for the time being, as his led me in the right direction). I will delete this answer if @belisarius chooses to move his answer here.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Scaled`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Scaled.html) coordinates can be quite helpful:

```
DynamicModule[{
  loc = Scaled[{0.5, 0.5}]},
 Column[{
   Plot[
    x, {x, 1, 2},
    Epilog -> Dynamic[ Point[Scaled[{loc[[1, 1]], loc[[1, 1]]}]] ]],
   Plot[
    x^2, {x, -1, 2},
    Epilog -> Dynamic@Locator[Dynamic[loc]]]
   }]
 ]
```

[image: some plots]

See how the point in the first coordinates follows quite nicely even though their ranges are completely different.

You can of course use [`EventHandler`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/EventHandler.html) with [`MousePosition`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MousePosition.html), which supports "GraphicsScaled" coordinates, instead of a `Locator`.

Comment: Thanks for the starter, @ssch! Indeed, your example worked up to the point of getting a locator to correspond to a depicted point on another graph. I wasn't aware of `DynamicModule`'s use in this way. However, I've edited my question to reflect a more involved aspect of my problem: my x-axes are not linear multiples of one another! Would you have any suggestion(s) as to how to approach this problem? Thank you.

Comment: @acheong87 I'd start by defining an invertible mapping between the two plotranges and use that to transform the location data.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = Table[{i, 5 Sin[i/10] + RandomReal[]}, {i, 100}];
data2 = {Log[#], #2} & @@@ data;
```

In case when you don't know how both axes are related to each other but only have point sets you can do something like:

```
Deploy@With[{opts = {Axes -> False, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> {300, 300/GoldenRatio}, 
             AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio}},
 DynamicModule[{sel = 1, mark},
  Column[{
          Graphics[{PointSize@.02, Dynamic@mark[data], 
                    Red, PointSize@.05, Dynamic@Point[data[[sel]]]}, opts],
          Graphics[{PointSize@.02, Dynamic@mark[data2], 
                    Red, PointSize@.05, Dynamic@Point[data2[[sel]]]}, opts]
        }]
  , Initialization :> (
 mark[data_] := MapIndexed[Dynamic@{If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], sel = First@#2];, 
                                       Point[#]} &, data];
  )]
]
```

[image]

Comment: I apologize I haven't had a chance to return to my project since the workweek began! I'll get to it later today, but this already looks like it's gonna do what I want. You guessed correctly that I have only point sets that map one-to-one, not a continuous function of any sort (though, I recall seeing an `Interpolate` function in Mathematica that might help with that). Can't wait to try this. (And I'll delete this otherwise frivolous comment.)

Comment: @acheong87 I'm looking forward hearing how it fits your needs :) If any improvements need to be done, just tell me. Good luck.

Comment: Your code, using 100 sample points, works. Unfortunately however, when I up the number of points to 6,300 (the typical size of my lists), Mathematica hangs at the "Formatting Notebook Contents" dialog, bringing up the "Disable Dynamic Evaluation" dialog every 10 seconds. Do you think perhaps the mouseover aspect consumes a lot of processing power? (I'm trying to remove that now, as I don't necessarily need hovering (clicking is sufficient). Or is it something else?

Comment: @acheong87 hi, sorry for delay, could you tell more about the data? Is the sampling constant etc? or you want a solution for just two list with arbitrary points related with pairs?

Comment: No problem! I should thank you. I learned a _ton_ over the past two days, starting from your code, and trying to modify it in various ways to do the minimum processing necessary. I know I probably could have been clearer about my data, too; I apologize. Two days ago, I didn't see my data that way, but yes, you're right, I have two arbitrarily lists, say `{{1,2},{3,4},{5,6},...}` and `{{10,20},{30,40},{50,60},...}` and need corresponding pairs to be "related," _e.g._ `{1,2}` and `{10,20}`. However, while asking a sub-question on another thread, @belisarius provided yet another answer, which I

Comment: have yet to investigate but soon will (hopefully tonight). I may ask him (or her) to post their solution here as well, but I upvoted you already because your solution _did_ work and technically answered by question, but just didn't quite perform well enough for larger datasets. Thanks again!

Comment: I've waited a while for \@belisarius to move his answer, but he hasn't. I'd like to re-accept my own copy of his answer because it was the most effective one (working for a large number of points) that may help future visitors. To compensate in rep, I've taken the time to read through a few of your other answers and questions on the site and upvoted two that I found personally interesting / helpful to know.

Comment: @acheong87 of course, accept what you find the most useful for you :)