# Efficiently searching a list for the position of the closest number to a specified number

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting, performance-tuning, searching

Searching by [closest](/questions/tagged/closest) and [position](/questions/tagged/position) I wasn't able to find an answer—but found [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/UsingNearest.html) by guessing. `Nearest`, however, returns the closest number itself, not the position.

After some more looking around, I learned about `MapIndexed` and `Rules`, and came up with this:

```
NearestPosition[haystack_, needle_] := Nearest[haystack, needle] /. MapIndexed[Rule, haystack];
```

Is there a more efficient way, in general?

(And what if it's guaranteed the list comes sorted—can that be leveraged?)

The reason I'm concerned about efficiency is that I intend to use `NearestPosition` in a `DynamicModule` where it may be triggered by every `mouseover` event. (I'm still trying to solve [this problem](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34434/hovering-mouse-cursor-over-a-plot-to-display-a-corresponding-point-in-another).)

Comment: thinking about it computationally, you'd need to check every number to determine which one is the closest number. So best you got is O(n). If it's sorted, you obviously can do a lot better by binary search and such. 

Anyway, what happens if there are multiple instances of the closest number? Do you expect it to take the closest or last?

Comment: @Jonie - Currently my implementation (above) returns what `Nearest` would return by default: a list of all "tied" for the closest. (I don't need any of `Nearest`'s other features, like closest-within-a-radius, closest-_n_, etc.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[42];
haystack = RandomReal[1, 6300];
AbsoluteTiming[
 f = Nearest[haystack -> Range@Length@haystack];
 {f[.3, 1], haystack[[f[.3, 1]]]}]

(*

-> {0.015625, {{3123}, {0.300033}}}

*)
```

Of course in this case most of the time is expended calculating the nearest function. If your points aren't changing from one use to the next, the time for calculating `f[}`is nil for 6K points.

The second argument of `f[]` specifies that `Nearest[]` should return only one point

Comment: You could use Automatic instead of Range.

Comment: Thanks for the cleaner solution. And indeed, I may be prematurely optimizing.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Yep, used it here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34620/193

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that I can precalculate something like `NearestFunction`. :)

Answer (score 5):

In versions 10+, you can have a `NearestFunction` that returns multiple properties, such as the `"Index"` of the nearest element and the `"Element"` itself:

```
SeedRandom[42];
haystack = RandomReal[1, 1000000];
f = Nearest[haystack ->{"Index", "Element"}];

AbsoluteTiming[f[.312345]]
```

> {0.000072, {{101999, 0.312345}}}

Comment: Could someone please explain this syntax: 'Nearest[haystack ->{"Index", "Element"}]'? In particular, I have trouble understanding the role and functioning of the rule ("->") operator here.

Comment: @BenjaminMárkus, see [Nearest >> Details and Options](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html) (and the examples 7 thru 10 in the section `Scope`.)