# Clicking on a point on a plot

Tags: plotting

I want to click on a plot and have the pointer snap to the actual curve displayed.
I found ways to click any random point on the plot but I want it to only click on actual points on the curve.

I want to read of the coordinates of the curve. But I dont want to read the coordinates of white space. I only want the curve. It'd also be great if I could drag the mouse and the point moves to the closes curve position to the mouse.

Comment: I believe this is related: [(34434)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34434/121)

Comment: Also related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34620/193

Comment: It is surprising that this functionality does not exist by default, it is very rudimentary. Maybe I was not clear enough?
This is what happens in matlab: https://i.imgur.com/tx9aQAD.png

Comment: It is done here with locators: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18090/