# What algorithm and tools should I use to search a data set for the point nearest to a given point?

Tags: algorithm, distance

I have about 1,000,000,000 points, which are the longitudes and latitudes of some places in a city, formatted like this: $(106.1231233,41.43234234)$. I also have about 20,000 points which are the longitudes and latitudes of some special places in this city. For every item in the 1,000,000,000 point data set, I have to compute which point in the 20,000 point data set is the nearest. If I were to compute on a brute-force, one by one basis, it might not complete during my lifetime. Is there an algorithm which can make this job less time-consuming? Can anyone help me?

Comment: You may be able to approach this using `Nearest`.

Comment: Just to clarify - is this about math/algorithms in general or specifically about the software *Mathematica* ?

Comment: If this is about Mathematica then the answer is `Nearest`.  If it is about algorithms and data structures, then I'd say it's off topic here and there are answers on StackOverflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9463165/data-structure-for-efficiently-retrieving-the-nearest-element-from-a-set).

Comment: To repeat what others have stated, you'll want to use `Nearest[<reference set>]`. Depending on specifics of locations, you may need to make adjustments to account for the fact that (long,lat) is not a Euclidean grid and moreover there is a singularity (crossover) for longitude.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**:

After reading about geodetic conversions, I decided to do a major rewrite.
Earlier versions can be found by clicking on the  "edited…" link.
No claims are made about speed.

My intuitions about Geodesy are rudimentary, so I relied on ideas encountered at
[Latitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude) and [Stack Exchange.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1185408/converting-from-longitude-latitude-to-cartesian-coordinates) I also

benefited from advice given by @Rahul Narain. Kuba also pointed me to an efficiency shortcut that [Belisarius](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34600/efficiently-searching-a-list-for-the-position-of-the-closest-number-to-a-specifi/34601#34601) had recently used.

```
(*Generate a random longitude in decimal degrees *)
rx:=RandomReal[{106.1000000000,106.2000000000},WorkingPrecision->10]

(*Generate a random latitude in decimal degrees *)
ry:=RandomReal[{41.4000000000,41.5000000000},WorkingPrecision->10]

(*radius of earth in km *)
r=6371;

(* 15 city points and 5 landmarks in Cartesian (XYZ) format *)
citypoints={r Cos[#2 Degree] Cos[# Degree],r  Cos[#2 Degree]Sin[# Degree],r Sin[#2 Degree]}&@@@Array[{rx,ry}&,15];
landmarks={r Cos[#2 Degree] Cos[# Degree],r  Cos[#2 Degree]Sin[# Degree],r Sin[#2 Degree]}&@@@Array[{rx,ry}&,5];

(* precomputed function for landmarks, to be used in Nearest *)
near=Nearest[landmarks];

(* each city point and its closest landmark *)
Grid[Prepend[{#,Nearest[landmarks,#][[1]]}&/@citypoints,{"city point","landmark"}],Dividers-> All]
```

### [image: table]

> Plot the city points and landmarks.  The origin is the center of the earth. x, y, z given in km.  The  picture in the right pane shows that the points appear to lie on a plane.  Of course, we know they lie on a sphere (or ellipsoid), but the curvature of the earth is imperceptible at this scale and point of view. (Remember: all the points lie in a single city.)

```
(* city points in red, landmarks in blue.  Lines connect each city point to the closest  
landmark *)
Graphics3D[{Red,PointSize[.03], Point@citypoints,Blue,Point@landmarks,
Black,Line[{#,Nearest[landmarks,#][[1]]}&/@citypoints]},AxesLabel->{"x","y","z"},BoxRatios->{1,-1,-1},Axes-> True,ViewPoint->{2,.5,.5}]
```

[image]

Comment: It will definitelly be faster if you precalculate `NearestFunction`: `near = Nearest[landmarks];
({#, near[#]} & /@ citypoints)`. Belisarius showed this [lately](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34601/5478)

Comment: You'll have to use `Nearest` with `GeoDistance` as the distance metric, not Euclidean. This will slow things down tremendously!

Comment: Presuming the long/lat, minutes, and seconds are converted to a single decimal, why won't euclidean work?  Besides, isn't this a one-off computation?

Comment: We are talking about 10^9 points here. I don't think the most obvious approaches will be useful here ...

Comment: @DavidCarraher Because 1 minute E from (0,0) is not the same distance as 1 minute N from (0,0). This difference only gets worse the closer you get to the poles. `GeoDistance` will tell you that, whereas `EuclideanDistance` will consider them both equally distant.

Comment: Since the points represent "some places in a city" and so are likely to be quite close together relative to the size of the Earth, it might be enough to scale the longitudes by $\cos\phi_m$, where $\phi_m$ is the mean latitude, and then continue to use Euclidean distances, no? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance#Spherical_Earth_projected_to_a_plane

Comment: Thanks rm-rf.  I'll look into this more closely

Comment: @Rahul.  Yes, good advice.  (Although I used different conversion formulas from decimal degrees to XYZ). Fortunately, Nearest can also handle distances in 3-space.

Comment: This is a nice approach, but your conversion formulas are incorrect, as you can see by the fact that `ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[#2 Degree], r Cos[# Degree], r Sin[#]} & @@ {lon, lat}, {lon, -180, 180}, {lat, -90, 90}]` is not a sphere. The formulas should be `{r Cos[#1 Degree] Cos[#2 Degree], r Cos[#1 Degree] Sin[#2 Degree], 
  r Sin[#1 Degree]} &` instead. Also you might want to use `BoxRatios -> Automatic` in the plot so that distances are shown without distortion.

Comment: @RahulNarain.  Thanks. That was due to sloppiness as well as misunderstanding the full meaning of the conversion formula. I did test the current formula using your criterion and it did produce a sphere, so I'm fairly certain that it now works.