# How can I find the point in a list of points that is nearest to a given point?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, programming, regions

I have a function $f(x)=\{\sin(x),\cos(x)\}$, $\,x=\{0,0.01,...,1\},$ and a point $P=\{2,3\}$.

I want to find the $x_0$ such that the distance between $P$ and $f(x_0)$ is minimum.

My code is:

```
f[x_] := {Sin[x], Cos[x]};
P = {2, 3};
data = f /@ Range[0, 1, 0.01];
Cases[Thread @ {Range[0, 1, 0.01], data}, {_, First @ Nearest[data, P]}][[1,1]]
```

Is there an easy method to for doing this?

Comment: @corey979 Sorry, I forgot the definition of f, thanks.

Comment: `MinimalBy[Range[0,1,0.01],EuclideanDistance[P,f[#]]&]`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [(34746)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34746). Also related: [(99244)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/99244)

Comment: Related:  [(20085)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/20085/121)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Using `Nearest`

I'd proceed along the lines

```
f[x_] := {x, Sin[x], Cos[x]};
data = f /@ Range[0, 1, 0.01];
P = {2, 3};
near = Nearest[Rest /@ data, P] (* only for comparison with further approaches *)
```

> {{0.556361, 0.830941}}

The position of `near` in `data` can be also obtained with `Nearest` directly:

```
loc = First @ Nearest[(Rest /@ data) -> Automatic, P]
```

> 60

so

```
x0 = (First /@ data)[[loc]]
```

> 0.59

### Exact solution - `Region` functions

The exact distance from the point `P` to the curve is

```
reg = ParametricRegion[Rest @ f[x], {{x, 0, 1}}];
FullSimplify @ RegionDistance[reg, P]
```

> $\sqrt{13}-1\approx 2.60555$

The coordinates (the equivalent of `near`) on this curve are (i.e., $p=\{\sin x_0, \cos x_0\}$)

```
RegionNearest[reg, P]
p = FullSimplify @ %
```

> $\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{13}},\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}\right)\approx \left( 0.5547, 0.83205\right)$

$x_0$ can be obtained with

```
sol = Solve[Rest @ f[x] == p, x] // First
```

[image]

hence

```
x0 = x /. sol /. C[1] -> 0
```

> $x_0=\arctan\frac{2}{3}\approx 0.588003$

### Exact solution - calculus

The distance and `x0` can be found numerically with

```
NMinimize[FullSimplify[EuclideanDistance[Rest @ f[x], P], x > 0], x]
```

> {2.60555, {x -> 0.588003}}

The exact value of `x0`:

```
g[x_] := FullSimplify[EuclideanDistance[Rest @ f[x], P], x > 0]
Solve[D[g[x], x] == 0, x]
```

[image]

so $x_0=\arccos\frac{3}{\sqrt{13}}$.

But because $x\in [0,1]$:

```
Solve[D[g[x], x] == 0 && 0 < x < 1, x]
```

[image]

All forms of the exact values of `x0` are equivalent:

```
ArcTan[2/3] == ArcCos[3/Sqrt[13]] == 2 ArcTan[1/2 (-3 + Sqrt[13])] // FullSimplify
```

> True

The last one can be also obtained with

```
ArgMin[EuclideanDistance[Rest @ f[x], P]^2, x]
```

from [Chip Hurst's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134386/how-can-i-find-the-point-in-a-list-of-points-that-is-nearest-to-a-given-point#comment362558_134388).

Comment: You could use `Nearest[(Rest /@ data) -> Automatic, P]` to have `Nearest` return the position rather than the value.

Comment: Also you could do `ArgMin[EuclideanDistance[Rest@f[x], P]^2, x]` for an exact solution (+1 by the way).

Comment: @ChipHurst Thanks; I edited to employ your `Nearest`.