# Calculate the mean distance between a set of points and a function efficiently

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, geometry

How to calculate efficiently the mean distance between a set of points and an (interpolating) function. The following minimal example does work but it seems a bit slow, especially with more points (takes about 1 second on my computer).

[image]

```
s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 11}];
pts = Table[{i, RandomReal[1]}, {i, 10}];
AbsoluteTiming[
  Sum[
    Sqrt[
      NMinimize[
        {
         (x - pts[[i, 1]])^2 + ((y[x] /. s[[1]]) - pts[[i, 2]])^2,
         0 <= x <= 11
        },
       x
      ][[1]]
    ],
  {i, Length[pts]}]/Length[pts]
]
```

This gives

```
{0.820107, 0.464279}
```

Comment: Related: [(134388)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134386/how-can-i-find-the-point-in-a-list-of-points-that-is-nearest-to-a-given-point/134388#134388). You might adapt those techniques for your needs.

Comment: without touching anything else, simply replacing `NMinimize` with `FindMinimum` gives a $\sim 2$ factor speedup. `NMinimize` is for global minimization problems, while `FindMinimum` for local minimization. In this case the latter is probably sufficient. Further removing the constraint on `x` from `FindMinimum` also gives you a dramatic improvement ($\sim 0.01$ s on my laptop to run the minimization vs the $\sim 0.9$ with the origin version).

Comment: Changing `s = NDSolve[...]` to `ss = NDSolveValue[...]` and doing `len = Length@pts; AbsoluteTiming[
 Total[Sqrt[Table[
     FindMinimum[(x - i)^2 + (ss[x] - pts[[i, 2]])^2, {x, 5.}][[1]]
     , {i, len}]]]/len
 ]` gives an answer in 0.006 s on my laptop, compared to 0.7 s. A broader note, since you are doing a least squares problem then `FindMinimum` has a method for that.

Comment: You seem to be minimizing distances from points to graph, which requires some flavor of optimization. But the wording suggests that what might be wanted is just the vertical discrepancies (distance between point and function evaluation). My question: is it really the point-to-graph distances that is desired?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can optimize within `NDSolve`.

OP's code, for comparison:

```
SeedRandom[0];  (* for reproducibility *)
pts = Table[{i, RandomReal[1]}, {i, 10}];
AbsoluteTiming[
 s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 11}];
 Sum[NMinimize[
   {(x - pts[[i, 1]])^2 + ((y[x] /. s[[1]]) - pts[[i, 2]])^2,
    0 <= x <= 11}, x][[1]],
  {i, Length[pts]}] / Length[pts]
 ]
(*  {0.784672, 0.23634}  *)
```

Collect the critical points in `NDSolve`, [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) the distances tagged by `dist[p]` for each point `p`, and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) the minima:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 dists = Last@Reap[
    sol = First@ NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1,
        Table[     (* a crit-pt event for each point *)
         With[{p = p}, 
          WhenEvent[Dot[{1, y'[x]}, p - {x, y[x]}] == 0, 
           Sow[Norm[p - {x, y[x]}], dist[p]]]],   (* sow distance tagged by dist[p] *)
         {p, pts}]}, 
       y, {x, 0, 11}];
    Do[               (* sow end points *)
     Sow[Norm[p - {0., y[0] /. sol}], dist[p]]; 
     Sow[Norm[p - {11., y[11] /. sol}], dist[p]],
     {p, pts}],
    dist /@ pts,      (* tags for reaping point by point *)
    Min[#2] &];       (* applied to each tag group of distances *)
 Total[dists, 2]/Length@pts
 ]
(*  {0.00991, 0.406317}  *)
```

Almost 80 times faster.

---

This is just as fast, or a bit faster, using `Nearest` to get a good seed for `FindMinimum`. Also Newton's method will be fast, but must be used on an unconstrained problem.  This could pose problems if the distance from a given point to the curve is decreasing at the endpoints of the curve.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 s = NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 11}];
 nf = Nearest[
   Transpose@{Flatten[y["Coordinates"] /. s], y["ValuesOnGrid"] /. First[s]} ->
    Flatten[y["Coordinates"] /. s]];
 Sum[Sqrt[FindMinimum[
      (x - pts[[i, 1]])^2 + ((y[x] /. s[[1]]) - pts[[i, 2]])^2,
      {x, First@nf@pts[[i]]}, Method -> "Newton"][[1]]],
   {i, Length[pts]}]/Length[pts]
 ]
```

> FindMinimum::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within the tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

```
(*  {0.008901, 0.406317}  *)
```

I'm not sure why `FindMinimum` has trouble with one of the points (the first in this case). That sometimes happens when using interpolating functions, but things seem well behaved near the minimum.